# Mac keyboard: different layout, same default shortcuts

Tags: mac, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout

I recently bought a new keyboard and, as I live in Brazil, got a ABNT2 keyboard (this one has a ç and accents on different places, [see here](https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Fi.stack.imgur.com%2FfpoHz.png&f=1&nofb=1))

The problem is: as a Mac user for some long time, I got used to the default US - International shortcuts (`option-e` to `é`, `option-n` to `˜`, etc).

Is there a way to keep this keyboard layout but replace these shortcuts?

Right now, `option-e = €` and `option-n = ŋ`

Comment: Theoretically, you could do it with something like [Ukelele](https://software.sil.org/ukelele/) - though I couldn't help with the specifics.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the asker gave up and got used to the new keyboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After two months, I found no answer.

I solved this getting used to the new keyboard.

Bummer.